# How can we connect 2 or more instances of the same program using code (java for example)? (multiboxing)

Tags: java, multibox

For example, I want to open 4 instances of a certain application, and I want an action on that instance to occur on all 4 instances, so all the process are connected, also known as multiboxing (usually done in games). I'm trying to do this in java and have no idea where to start. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try Remote Method Invocation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

Comment: A more concrete example of multiboxing might help.  It appears that your application would benefit from the [model/view/controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  [Java socket programming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html) might be useful.